# How to solve this limit without using L'Hopital's Rule: $\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\sqrt{x^4\cos^2{x}+2x^2\sin^2{2x}-x^4}}{x^2}$?

Tags: limits

> **Find:**
>   $$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\sqrt{x^4\cos^2{x}+2x^2\sin^2{2x}-x^4}}{x^2}\cdot$$

I tried to simplify the expression, but I kept getting stuck. I also tried to make a substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$, but I got stuck again. Please give me hint or explain what to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{\sqrt{x^4\cos^2{x}+2x^2\sin^2{2x}-x^4}}{x^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0^-}\sqrt{\cos^2{x}+\frac{8\sin^2{2x}}{(2x)^2}-1}$$
$$=\sqrt{8}$$
$$=2\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Factor by $x^4$ inside the square root and simplify by $x^2$.

then using the classical limit
$$\lim_0\frac {\sin (X)}{X}=1$$

we get $$2\sqrt {2} $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that, as $x \to 0$, we have
$$
\sin x \sim x \implies\sin^2(2x)\approx4x^2 
\\ \cos x \sim1 \implies\cos^2(x)\approx1
$$
We can use these to greatly simplify the limit at hand:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x^4\cos^2{x}+2x^2\sin^2{2x}-x^4}}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{8x^4}}{x^2} = \color{red}{\sqrt 8}$$

If you want a mor rigorous proof, we can instead use squeeze theorem or $O$ notation. Using the latter, we can write $\sin^2(2x) \in 4x^2 + O(x^6)$ and $\cos^2(x) \in 1+O(x^4)$ as $x \to 0$, giving us

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x^4\cos^2{x}+2x^2\sin^2{2x}-x^4}}{x^2} &=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x^4[1+O(x^4)]+2x^2[4x^2+O(x^6)]-x^4}}{x^2}
\\&=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x^4+8x^4+O(x^8)-x^4}}{x^2}
\\&=\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{\frac{8x^4+O(x^8)}{x^4}}
\\&=\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{8+O(x^4)}
\\&=\sqrt{8+\lim_{x \to 0}O(x^4)}
\\&= \color{red}{\sqrt 8}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^4\cos^2{x}+2x^2\sin^2{2x}-x^4}}{x^2} = \frac{\sqrt{x^4\cos^2{x}+8x^2 \sin^2x \cos^2x-x^4}}{x^2}=
\frac{\sqrt{x^4(\cos^2{x}-1)+8x^2 \sin^2x \cos^2x}}{x^2}=
\frac{\sqrt{-x^4\sin^2 x+8x^2 \sin^2x \cos^2x}}{x^2} =
\frac{\sqrt{x^2\sin^2 x(8 \cos^2x - x^2)}}{x^2} =
\frac{\sqrt{\sin^2 x(8 \cos^2x - x^2)}}{x} =
\sqrt{ \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 (8 \cos^2x - x^2)}
$$
Now, take the limit
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\sqrt{ \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 (8 \cos^2x - x^2)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\sqrt{ \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2} \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\sqrt{(8 \cos^2x - x^2)} = 1 \times \sqrt{8} = 2\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

*Just added as a too long comment.*

Many ways to get the answer have been given in answers. Using Taylor expansions with one more term, you could even know how is approached the limit since $$x^4 \cos ^2(x)+2 x^2 \sin ^2(2 x)=9 x^4-\frac{35 x^6}{3}+O\left(x^8\right)$$ making $$x^4 \cos ^2(x)+2 x^2 \sin ^2(2 x)-x^4=8 x^4-\frac{35 x^6}{3}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
$$\sqrt{x^4 \cos ^2(x)+2 x^2 \sin ^2(2 x)-x^4}=2 \sqrt{2}\, x^2-\frac{35 }{12 \sqrt{2}}x^4+O\left(x^6\right)$$ $$\frac{\sqrt{x^4\cos^2{x}+2x^2\sin^2{2x}-x^4}}{x^2}=2 \sqrt{2}-\frac{35 x^2}{12 \sqrt{2}}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Moreover, this provides an easy *estimation* of the function "close" to $x=0$. For example $$x=\frac \pi 6 \implies \text{exact} \approx 2.28503 \qquad  \text{approximation} \approx 2.26301$$ 
$$x=\frac \pi 4 \implies \text{exact} \approx 1.65598 \qquad  \text{approximation} \approx 1.55624$$

Comment: nice explanation

Answer (score 0):

The expression in square roots can be simplified as $$8x^{2}\sin^{2}x\cos^{2}x-x^{4}\sin^{2}x$$ and hence the numerator becomes $$x\sin x\sqrt{8\cos^{2}x - x^{2}} $$ and thus we can see that the given expression can be written as $$\frac{\sin x} {x} \cdot\sqrt{8\cos^{2}x-x^{2}}\to 1\cdot \sqrt{8\cdot 1^{2}-0^{2}}=2\sqrt{2}$$ and thus the desired limit is $2\sqrt{2}$.